# Magento category <-> product <-> website relationship

Tags: magento

How exactly are products related to a category, and a category to a website?

I have the following setup in Magento:

1) I have three websites in one installation (country specific)

2) Each of those tree websites has three store views (language specific)

So, in total there are 10 core_store (1 admin + 9).

My goal is to support the following scenarios:

1) Each of the websites has the same categories, however, some are not active for some websites.

2) A product can be a part of one category in website X and not a part of the same category in website Y. It can also be a part of the same category in website X and website Y

3) A category might be active for website X but not active for website Y

I would like to know how those "entities" relate on a database level/configuration level. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you seek to do can be done.

It is often the case that one needs to write out the scoping scenarios and then dig through the admin interface to see what's possible, as some things cannot be set at the website level.

- Products: `catalog_product_entity`
- Categories: `catalog_category_entity`
- Websites: `core_website`
- Stores: `core_store`

Categories disabled at the store level by setting the category's is_active ("Active") value to 0 ("No") at the store level. This means that "hiding" a category for a given website requires setting the category to inactive for each of the website's store views. This can be done in code using update scripts, in the database directly, or in the admin panel. Via the admin this is done by editing the category and using the store switcher:

[image: Store Switcher in Category admin]

Product's websites association can be similarly edited individually (using the "Websites" tab) or en masse using the filters and mass action block's "Update Attributes" function at the top of the grid.

Additionally, if one needs to change categorization for a website then a new root category is called for.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I believe what I need are separate root categories per website. This will give me the flexibility of linking products to different category entities (although they actually have the same name).